How to conditionally pull from an extra repo based on profile substring in Config Server
We have a config repository that is shared by some (but not all) of our apps that use our Spring Cloud Config Server. The apps declare that they want these shared configs by providing one or more profiles that contain the string "RMQ" (e.g. "RMQ_Main", "RMQ_Results", "RMQ_Client").
We are using the bootstrap file still. (We have other needs that would prevent us from using spring.config.import.) Here is a bare bones example of what we are currently doing:
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        composite:
        -
          type: git
          searchPaths: "*, SpecialFolder/*"            
          uri: ${base-uri}/{application}.git
        -
          type: git
          uri: ${base-uri}/configserverplaceholder.git

          repos:
            RabbitMQ:
              pattern: '*/*RMQ*'
              uri: ${SharedRabbitMQURI}
              searchPaths: /*, SharedDomains/*

It works. However, we have to specify that top-level entry for ${base-uri}/configserverplaceholder.git that just points to an empty repo (ConfigServerPlaceholder) that we created. We then have to add release branches to that repo to avoid NoSuchLabelException. If a user wants to test against a feature branch, they have to create that branch in the ConfigServerPlaceholder. The reason we have the "RabbitMQ" entry is the need for "pattern", which isn't supported at the higher level.
Is there a way to accomplish our needs without use of this ConfigServerPlaceholder entry?
To make our requirements clear:

If a request is made and profiles include "RMQ" in the string, include the configuration from SharedRabbitMQURI. (Example: {config_server}/application1/RMQ_Main,RMQ_Result,prd/release(_)6677)
If a request is made and profiles do not include "RMQ" in the string, do not include the configuration from SharedRabbitMQURI. (Example: {config_server}/application1/prd/release(_)6677)

